# UITextField Alignment : Placeholder right aligned & Actual text gets left aligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, ios9

I have a `UITextField` set in `xib`. Text `Alignment` is set to `right`. When app is running, I see `textfield` which shows `placeholder` with `right aligned` text. When I start typing it still aligned to `right`. As soon as I move the cursor from that `textfield` to some other UI component, typed text gets `left aligned`.

**EDIT :**
I have resolved it partially in one scenario while editing in textField. But direct text assignment from local data source having same problem.

**Editing Text Field Solution**

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   textField.text = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

**Still facing alignment issue if I say,**

```
textField.text = @"my Test";
```

Applied same logic before assigning text to textField as did in editing mode but still it gets left aligned automatically :(

**Actual Output Problem**

[image]

**`XIB` Setting for `UITextField`**

[image]

Comment: why is text field alignment and control horizontal alignment different ?

Comment: @Alok, Even though I change control alignment to right, no change in result.

Comment: @Ameer any luck ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Jeff No luck on this yet for setting text.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using a `UILabel` category class for vertical alignment adjustment. In that there was a method `+(void)load`and inside that method i was using following line

```
method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)), class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(verticalAlignTextRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)));
method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(drawTextInRect:)), class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(verticalAlignDrawTextInRect:)));
```

This particular lines of code caused the problem for me. It was overriding the existing default behaviour of the `UITexfield`.  Commenting this worked for me.
So something similar would be there in your code also.
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I was using method_exchangeImplementations in one of my category, commenting it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as same as you performed and it's working fine.
I think You have to delete that **textfield** and put it again with new identity.
Then Clean and Rebuild your project.

Make sure You are not giving any values or parameters to **textfield** programatically.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I deleted textfield & added it back But still same result.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have mentioned about "Dont give any values programatically"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
1- set the textAligment to the right
2- add UITextFieldDelegate to your.h
3- yourTextField.delegate = self
4- Add the delegate method 'willBeginEditing' and set the textfield aligment to the left inside it
5- Add the delegate method 'didEndEditing' and set the textfield aligment to the right inside it IF the textfield.text is = @""

Happy Coding!

Comment: It didn't work .I have partially got solution.Plz see Edit part of my updated post. Thanks for your input Bashir